# How does one manage the default namespaces in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, namespaces

A fresh install of Netbeans for PHP shows the following namespaces for code completion:

CommonMark, Ds, Gender, HRTime, MongoDB, Parle, Swoole, UI, Vtiful, XMLDiff, mysql_xdevapi, pht, and wkhtmltox

Is there a way to remove these libraries (I do not need them), so they do not "pollute" the global namespace?

I've searched the Preferences dialog, the plugins (all are disabled), the file system including the hidden stuff, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The information is stored in

⁨NetBeans 11.app⁩ ▸ ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Resources⁩ ▸ ⁨NetBeans⁩ ▸ ⁨php⁩ ▸ ⁨docs⁩ ▸ ⁨phpsigfiles.zip

I unzipped phpsigfiles.zip, removed all files containing namespaces and compressed the folder to phpsigfiles.zip.

Of course when updating NetBeans it will have to be done again. Unfortunate that there is no way to disable this in the IDE, as these are extensions and not part of PHP core (they are called "PHP Other Basic Extensions").